# Не компилируется программа со считыванием строки

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Работаю в самой последней версии Visual Studio. Ещё при самом написании кода функция gets "подчеркнулась" волнистой линией. Вроде бы всё в самом коде нормально. Может это специфика самой среды или сама функция устарела... Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a[80];

    cout << "Vvedite stroku: ";
    gets(a);

    cout << "Vasha stroka: ";
    cout << a;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Наверное, нужно подключать `cstdio.h`, потому что `gets` это не стандартная библиотека

Comment: Неа, не получается

Comment: Какую ошибку при компиляции выдает?

Comment: Функция `gets` была удалена из стандартной библиотеки еще в 2011 году. Нет больше такой функции. Да и к чему вам мешать С++ ввод-вывод с С вводом-выводом? Пользуйтесь средствами С++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте `cin.get(a, 80);` или `cin.getline(a, 80);` вместо `gets(a);`

Синтаксис:

```
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
```

где s - указатель на массив char'ов, в который вы будете писать, n - максимальное количество символов, которые вы хотите записать (включая последний нулевой символ), delim - символ, нахождение которого прекращает ввод. Подробнее, но на английском [тут](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/).

В VS использовать `gets` не выйдет:

> Эти функции устарели. Начиная с Visual Studio 2015 они недоступны в
>   CRT. Безопасные версии этих функций, gets_s и _getws_s, по-прежнему
>   доступны. Сведения об этих альтернативных функциях см. в статье
>   gets_s, _getws_s.

Подробнее по [ссылке](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2029ea5f.aspx) на msdn.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> gets(a);
> ```

```
fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin);
```